# Is there any way to create video-like animation with javascript ?

Tags: javascript, animation, web

As we know, The common animation in the web is event-driven. We can easily play animation with an event.

But I want to know that is there any way to create video-like animation with javascript?

What I want is when I open a page, the browser preload all my meterial(images and music). After that, the animation play automatically.

I can only think out an inefficient way by using css3 transition animation and javascript to do this.

Define css3 transition animation.

```
.test1 {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
}

.test2 {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.test3 {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

Use `setTimeout` function

```
var ele1 = document.getElementById('t1');
var ele2 = document.getElementById('t2');
var ele3 = document.getElementById('t3');

setTimeout(function () {
    ele1.className += 'test1';
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
    ele2.className += 'test2';
}, 3000);

setTimeout(function () {
    ele3.className += 'test3';
}, 5000);
```

Is there any third-party tools can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create such animations rather easily with something like [Adobe Edge](http://html.adobe.com/edge/animate/) or Google's [Web Designer](https://www.google.com/webdesigner/)

Comment: I have no experience with Web Designer, but I have to use Adobe Edge at work and for WYSIWYG editor it ain't half that bad after you get over the learning curve. I mostly do every else by hand expect the complex animations like you described.